# Open new windws with kiosk and chromium-args

Tags: nw.js

I am trying to build a kisok app that open a webpage in a new window. And on that new window i want to add the rule that only that webpage is allowed. But it seams that chromium-args is not a valid option on the open function. So if that option is not allowed how do i solv this problem?

```
var new_win = gui.Window.open('https://github.com', {
    kiosk: true,
    'chromium-args' : '--host-rules="MAP * github.com"'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [window event new-win-policy](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Window#new-win-policy):

```
function (frame, url, policy) {}
```

Emitted when a new window is requested from this window or a child iframe, e.g. user clicks a link with _blank target.

policy is an object with the following methods:

- `ignore()` : ignore the request, navigation won't happen.
- `forceCurrent()` : force the link to be opened in the same frame
- `forceDownload()` : force the link to be a downloadable, or open by
  external program
- `forceNewWindow()` : force the link to be opened in a new window
- `forceNewPopup()` : force the link to be opened in a new popup window
- `setNewWindowManifest(m)` : control the options for the new popup
  window. The object m is in the same format as the window subfield in
  Manifest format (e.g. `{"frame" : false}`). since v0.11.3

Code is next:

```
var new_win = gui.Window.open('https://github.com', { kiosk: true });
new_win.on('new-win-policy', function (frame, url, policy) {
    policy.ignore()
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i will look in to that. But can the user go to a new page on the same domain? http://www.example.com/index.html to index2.html?

Comment: It works, 100%, I used it. What version of nwjs? Some versions of nwjs can have bugs (was some problems in 0.13.X versions and in some very early versions).Try latest nwjs or 0.12.3.